# How to determine the source columns in a linked Access Table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a linked table in my MS Access 2010 Database. The table is importing 9 columns from a text file that contains approx. 150 columns.

**- Is there anyway to modify the linked table and change one column but keep the rest?**

My research on the web thus far has indicated that this is not possible. I wanted to ask the question here to verify. Seemingly this would be a problem that many users encounter, so there must be an intelligent solution to this problem, or at least a decent workaround.

**- Should the answer to the first question be "no", is there at least a way to determine which columns are being pulled from the source file?**

**UPDATE:**
As suggested in the comments I am including the design view Description Property of my table. Unfortunately it only provides the File Source.

```
Text;DSN=Olsdrdp_offerttool Link Specification2;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=1252;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=W:\FTP\ITS150\07_Model_Pfos;TABLE=olsdrdp_offerttool#csv
```

Comment: Open the linked table in design view, open the property sheet. **Description** contains the .Connect property, please add this to the question (or maybe it will already have the answer).

Comment: The design view *Description* property  gives me only the File Source but not the fields. The Field Names have been renamed by the person who created the original import, so I can't tell from where they are coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it provides a lot more. :)
In Access Navigation options (the F11 sidebar), enable System objects.
There are tables `MSysIMEXSpecs` and `MSysIMEXColumns`. (IMEX = Import Export)

`IMEX=2` should mean that the SpecID 2 is used for the linked table, `DSN=Olsdrdp_offerttool Link Specification2` is probably the SpecName.

If you filter `MSysIMEXColumns` by SpecID=2, you should see the imported columns.

You can also start the Text import wizard for the csv file:

[image]

and via "Extended" button ("Erweitert" in German) load the Import specification "Olsdrdp_offerttool Link Specification2".

To change the linked table (i.e. create a new linked table), complete the Import wizard, creating a new import specification at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much! Herzlichen Dank! :- ) I knew there had to be some way to do it...